# Users don't see permission for Slash Commands

Tags: slack, slack-api

When users try adding a Slack app we created via our website, we have set to ask permissions for these scopes below:

```
channels:read
chat:write
chat:write.public
commands
groups:read
im:read
incoming-webhook
mpim:read
users:read
users:read.email
```

However, users are not able to see the `commands` scope described as `Perform actions in your workspace` by Slack on the permissions screen. And since this scope is not shown to them, they are never able to use the Slash commands we have created for them.

Additional information:

1. I created a new workspace and added our Slack app but it didn't work
2. Two workspaces are seeing the slash commands which others are not
3. Our app is not approved as of yet though I don't feel it must be causing an issue

Comment: And you've verified that the `commands` scope is included in your authorization url (`https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize...`)? Also, sounds like your app is public? Are the slash commands you've created new? If so, make sure those changes have been submitted and approved by the App directory team.

Comment: @sandra after a lot of digging, we found out that we hadn't added `commands` in our OAuth URLs thus causing issues, stupid mistake. Not deleting this question in case someone stumbles upon this.

Comment: Not stupid! It happens more often than you'd think.